# HttpExceptionRequest (CertificateUnknown) running stack setup

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

```
$ stack setup -v
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd i386 hpack-0.17.0
2017-05-26 07:40:44.945473: [debug] Checking for project config at: C:\development\repos\eta\stack.yaml
@(Stack\Config.hs:935:9)
2017-05-26 07:40:44.948475: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml
@(Stack\Config.hs:960:13)
2017-05-26 07:40:44.954477: [debug] Trying to decode C:\sr\build-plan-cache\i386-windows\lts-6.27.cache
@(Data\Store\VersionTagged.hs:68:5)
2017-05-26 07:40:44.964480: [debug] Success decoding C:\sr\build-plan-cache\i386-windows\lts-6.27.cache
@(Data\Store\VersionTagged.hs:72:13)
2017-05-26 07:40:44.975485: [debug] Using standard GHC build
@(Stack\Setup.hs:600:9)
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/fpco/stackage-content/master/stack/stack-setup-2.yaml"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (InternalException (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("certificate rejected: [InvalidSignature SignatureInvalid]",True,CertificateUnknown))))
```

I'm running Windows 10 and get the same error in GitBash, Cygwin and DOS Command Line, both as User and as Administrator.

I have tried fetching the file into IE (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/stackage-content/master/stack/stack-setup-2.yaml) as suggested for similar issues regarding the retrieval of files from GitHub. I can get the file but stack still fails afterwards.

Following comments I also tried curl from GitBash and get

```
* About to connect() to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 151.101.48.133...
* Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.48.133) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Users\pauldenby\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I am currently trying to import the missing certs into curl-ca-bundle.crt but I'm not sure that'll help with the fundamental problem. Is it documented anywhere where stack will look for trusted CAs?

I can also run curl --insecure. As a very temporary workaround, is there anything similar for stack?

Comment: Can you fetch the file/path using `curl`? (I'm not sure though, if there is `curl` for Windows.)

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2536

Comment: Added curl response to OP